# Delete redis document by criteria shellscript

Tags: shell, redis

I am  using really awesome plugin for my node.js project which uses Redis , since I am familiar with other databases and need this one time only I am looking for shellscript which delete / empty / remove documents from what I undestand are :

`q:job:state = "complete"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a task queue and you want to remove completed tasks, you could approach it differently. 
For example you could have a [Redis list](http://redis.io/commands#list) for your queue

Then you could use the the lpop to take the first task from your queue and execute it. The lpop fetches the first value of the list and also removes it. 
In case that the job was not successfull you could use lpush ot rpush in order to put the task back to the queue as first or last value respectively, to be re-executed.